# What is Cassini's (aka VS Dev Server) stack limit?

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, stack-overflow, cassini

I'm running into a StackOverflowException (please don't ask, it's not my fault) in IIS6/2k3 which has a limit of 256k, but the exception *doesn't happen* in the VS debugger.

As a matter of understanding I'd love to know, but have failed to google what the stack limit of Cassini is...if indeed it has one?

Comment: fwiw, I fixed the problem (colleagues declaring *vast* arrays) - but the symptom, and the question remain unsolved.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried stack-overflowing Cassini on purpose to see at what point it crashes? I'd imagine the stack is immense, though I would expect Cassini to replicate IIS as closely as possible. It's surprising that something that runs in VS wouldn't run in IIS, and I'd even consider [filing a VS bug with Microsoft](http://blogs.msdn.com/astebner/articles/451329.aspx), since it seems that the whole point of Cassini is to replicate the functionality of IIS and provide an ideal debugging environment, since any web projects you write in VS will inherently be deployed against IIS.

I'm not sure if [this forum thread](http://forums.iis.net/t/1153323.aspx) was posted by you, or if you've seen it, but he seems to have the exact same problem, in case you're still experiencing it.

Comment: Nope, that's not me (JScript.Net? eww). I did try a test to see what the stack limit was for cassini but it blew VS so AFAIK there would appear to be *no* limit or if there is, it's associated with VS. My recommendation is to attach VS to IIS early in development.

Comment: I don't think that was Cassini's explicit & only purpose, to replicate IIS. I think it's main goal was to ease & speed development time. That being said, it would be nice if they were the same. But they are probably different enough to have different stack limits. In theory, you just don't hit them.